# Find the sums of the series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$
1-  \frac{1}{5 \cdot 3^2} - \frac{1}{7 \cdot 3^3} +  \frac{1}{11 \cdot 3^5} +  \frac{1}{13 \cdot 3^6} - - + + \cdots
$$

Not really sure how to start the problem, and help will be grateful

Comment: Well, on average, the grateful will be helped.

Comment: A good start would be "the $n$-th denominator is the $(n+1)$-th prime multiplied by $3$ to the ???-th power". You must be more specific about the pattern of the summands.

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas, I suspect the extra numbers in the denominators are the odd numbers not divisible by 3. In which case there is a trick for doing this.

Comment: Can you put this in $\Sigma$ notation. The pattern has me flummoxed.....

Comment: Actually, more than one trick is involved, so I will wait on developments.

Comment: @Will, he who hesitates is lost.

Comment: @Gerry, he who takes a nap wakes up refreshed.

Answer (score 4):

First, rewrite the series $$1 - \frac{1}{5 \cdot 3^2} - \frac{1}{7 \cdot 3^3} + \frac{1}{11 \cdot 3^5} + \frac{1}{13 \cdot 3^6} - \cdots=\\=3^\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3^\frac12} - \frac{1}{5 \cdot 3^\frac52} - \frac{1}{7 \cdot 3^\frac72} + \frac{1}{11 \cdot 3^\frac{11}2} + \frac{1}{13 \cdot 3^\frac{13}2} - \cdots\right)$$ Now, define a function $f:(-1,1)\to\mathbb R$ by $$f(x)=x-\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+\frac{x^{11}}{11}+\frac{x^{13}}{13}-\cdots$$ Note that $$f'(x)=1-x^4-x^6+x^{10}+x^{12}-\cdots$$ This is a geometric series, so we may sum it using the usual formula and obtain $$f'(x)=\frac{1-x^4}{1+x^6} =\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4}.$$ We may now integrate this (using partial fraction decomposition; this requires some work, so we leave it as an exercise to the reader) and use the fact that $f(0)=0$ to obtain a closed form expression for $f$. The answer is then obtained by evaluating $3^\frac12f(3^{-\frac12})$.

Comment: If it is not clear that $f^\prime$ is a geometric series, it may help to write $f^\prime(x) = (1-x^4)(1-x^6+x^{12}+\cdots)$.

Comment: Very nice work.  I also like the wording "...this requires some work, and so we leave it as an exercise to the reader..."  I'm going to borrow that, I sense...